# How to check existence of an object using pk in django template?

Tags: python, django

I tried this `if condition` to show previous and next posts only if it exists in database.

```
{% if blog.pk|add:-1 %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog:blogdetail' blog.pk|add:-1  %}">Previous Post</a>
{% endif %}

{% if blog.pk|add:1 %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog:blogdetail' blog.pk|add:1  %}">Next Post</a>
{% endif %}
```

but, it kinda ignores the condition and always show next and previous posts buttons owing to the fact that this condition is wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please *don't* do this in the template. It is a bad idea to write business logic in the template.

Comment: thank you, any solution. How to do it in view and pass it in template

Comment: I think the only option left is the create two foreign key fields referring to the same model and manually tell which is previous and next posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, *don't* implement this in the template. Templates should be used for *rendering logic*, not *business logic*.

You can define a method for example on your `Post` object to obtain the previous and next item:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    # …

    def get_next(self):
        return Blog.objects.filter(pk__gt=self.pk).order_by('pk').first()
    
    def get_previous(self):
        return Blog.objects.filter(pk__lt=self.pk).order_by('-pk').first()
```

Then you thus can use these methods:

```
{% with prev_blog=blog.get_previous %}
  {% if prev_blog %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog:blogdetail' prev_blog.pk %}">Previous Post</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

{% with next_blog=blog.get_next %}
  {% if next_blog %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog:blogdetail' next_blog.pk %}">Next Post</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

This will also fetch `Blog` objects if there is a "gap". So if there is no `Blog` object with `pk=4`, then the `get_previous` of a `Blog` with `pk=5`, will be a `Blog` with `pk=3`.

Comment: Thank you sir, you were always there and we appreciate it and this is exactly what i need.